# What is the best way to detect if an image is pixelated?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to tell whether an image is pixelated or not. I was trying to use the laplacian variance method to do this, but I'm not sure that it is working correctly because a pretty distorted/pixelated image comes back with a very high variance of 1011 using my code:

```py
import sys
import cv2
import imutils as im

csv_filename = sys.argv[1]

def variance_of_laplacian(image):
    # compute the Laplacian of the image and then return the focus
    # measure, which is simply the variance of the Laplacian
    # image = cv2.copyMakeBorder(image, 100, 100, 100, 100, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value = [255, 255, 255])
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        # invert gray image
    gray = 255 - gray
    # cv2.imshow("result", gray)
    # cv2.waitKey(0)
    laplacian_var = cv2.Laplacian(gray, cv2.CV_64F).var()
    return laplacian_var

image = im.url_to_image(sys.argv[1])
laplacian_var = variance_of_laplacian(image)
print laplacian_var
```

Is there another method to detect pixelation in an image or something like that?

Here is one image that I would deem pixelated/distorted/blurry for my tests:
[image: test image]

Comment: Where does `.var()` originate?

Comment: This really doesn't seem like an answerable question, at least not without more constraints on the types of images you expect. What do "distorted" and "pixelated" mean? The Laplacian could be equally high for a perfect checkerboard as for a "distorted" image, for example.

Comment: @fmw42 I'm not sure exactly. I was using this [site](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/07/blur-detection-with-opencv/) as a reference for the laplacian portion.

Comment: @bnaecker the types of images I will have are product images. Meaning a white background and then a single product in the center (ideally at least). So in my case, a pixelated image would be a jar of mayonnaise that was resized larger and thus makes the text and other areas look rough and distorted. Sorry if I didn't explain it well.

Comment: Could you provide your source image?

Comment: @AndreySmorodov I have just added one of my source images to my post

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue has to do with ".var()". I do not know what that is. But here is one way to do what you want using numpy.var().

**But note, that the variance of the laplacian is not a good way to test for pixelation unless you know you have the same image.**

Original Input:

[image]

Pixelated Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read original and pixelated image
img1 = cv2.imread('mandril3.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('mandril3_pixelated.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# compute laplacians
laplacian1 = cv2.Laplacian(gray1,cv2.CV_64F)
laplacian2 = cv2.Laplacian(gray2,cv2.CV_64F)

# get variances
variance1 = np.var(laplacian1)
variance2 = np.var(laplacian2)
print ('variance of original image:', variance1)
print ('variance of pixelated image:', variance2)

# save images
cv2.imwrite('mandril3_laplacian.png', (255*laplacian1).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))
cv2.imwrite('mandril3_pixelated_laplacian.png', (255*laplacian2).clip(0,255).astype(np.uint8))

# show laplacian using OpenCV
cv2.imshow("laplacian1", laplacian1)
cv2.imshow("laplacian2", laplacian2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Laplacian of original image:

[image]

Laplacian of pixelated image:

[image]

Variance Results:

```
variance of original image: 4014.7300553284585
variance of pixelated image: 779.2810668945312
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to tell if an image is pixelated. Decimate it at two different offsets for the same skip factor and compute the mean of the absolute difference. If the mean is zero, it is pixelated.

In the following, I use a skip of 2 and and offset of 0 and 1.

Original image:

[image]

Pixelated image:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read original and pixelated image
img1 = cv2.imread('mandril3.jpg')
img2 = cv2.imread('mandril3_pixelated.png')

# decimate images by some skip factor (2) for two different offsets (0 and 1)
dec1A = img1[::2, ::2]
dec1B = img1[1::2, 1::2]
dec2A = img2[::2, ::2]
dec2B = img2[1::2, 1::2]

# get mean of absolute difference
diff1 = cv2.absdiff(dec1A, dec1B)
mean1 = np.mean(diff1)
diff2 = cv2.absdiff(dec2A, dec2B)
mean2 = np.mean(diff2)
print('mean absdiff original image:', mean1)
print('mean absdiff pixelated image:', mean2)

# convert to grayscale
gray1 = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray2 = cv2.cvtColor(img2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Mean results:

```
mean absdiff original image: 20.53973388671875
mean absdiff pixelated image: 0.0
```

Comment: So this would only work if I knew I had the same image, correct? In my situation, there will be many different images, so I can't really make a baseline to compare it to. I guess this issue is much more difficult than I originally thought. I just hoped there was a way for me to know if images coming in were blurry/pixelated/distorted without manually checking.

Comment: Pixelation tests as I describe below would not work for testing if blurry or otherwise distorted. There is no way to know if an image is distorted in geometrical sense. Nor is there a good way to know if blurry. Blurry measure are the variance or standard deviation, but again compared to an original. Two totally different images could neither be blurry, but one might have a much lower variance than the other simply because one has large regions of constant color. Pixelation can be measured as I describe below.

Comment: So are you saying it is basically impossible to do what I am wanting to? Is there anything else you can think of to be able to flag an image as sharp or pixelated/distorted/blurry without a reference image? Or am I just out of luck of this one?

Comment: Pixelation can be detected as I have shown below. But I know of no way to tell if any random image is warped or blurry. Certain types of blur can be detected such as motion blur and defocus. But those usually require rather ideal situations.

Comment: I see. That is unfortunate. I'll have to keep searching then.

Answer (score 0):

If we will apply FFT on your image, we will see lins, not very obvious but visible:

[image: Fourier transform]

Marked here:

[image: Detect lines]

You can compute histograms along X and Y axis, and find if there are pikes. If pikes are higher than defined threshold, you have pixelated image.

You can do fast experimaens using application:  http://www.jcrystal.com/products/ftlse/index.htm

Comment: The question is not about generating pixelated images, but how to detect if the image have been pixelated.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Changed my answer.

Comment: Spikes in a histogram from the FFT can simply be due to other effects or from an image of a grid or checkerboard. So those are not really pixelated in the same sense.

Comment: Yes, but checkerboard is a variant of pixelated image. Yes there are special cases (any regular structures). But any method detecting pixelation will detect regularity, so it seems general problem. But you can reduce side effects by setting valid frequency ranges.

Comment: Agreed. In summary, you can detect most reasonable cases, but there will be  false alarms from images with repetitive patterns.