# Finding spikes in FFT histogram

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy, fft

I want to find if an image has blockiness. Like in the image [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sego_lily_cm-150.jpg). So this is what I am doing. I take the fourier transform and check if there are spikes. I got to try this method from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61943223/1420429).

```
im = cv2.imread('image1.jpg') 
gray= cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
fft = np.fft.fft2(gray) fftShift = np.fft.fftshift(fft)
```

The answer says to "compute histograms along X and Y axis, and find if there are spikes. If spikes are higher than defined threshold, you have pixelated image." I know there is `find_peaks` in `scipy.signal` module. But I do not know how exactly to use it for this purpose or if there is a better way of doing it. Can someone please help?

I only have the pixelated image, I do not have the original image.

Comment: I wonder if this is the right way to go about it. Because the FFT for a clear image with many strong edges would also have spikes in the histograms along X and Y axis

Comment: @JeruLuke I am assuming that for a clear image with many strong edges there will be less spikes when compared with an image with blockiness. Is that wrong? Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: There is only one way to find out.. by experimenting :) I tried finding the standard deviation of FFT values along X and Y axis but not able to conclude anything from it. And if you analyse the FFT for the given age after converting to `uint8`, there are many low values more like pepper being sprinkled. Maybe that could give us some clue